# comando updatebd no funciona, intento descargar las dependencias pero sigue sin funcionar

Tags: linux, terminal

cuando ejecuto el comando sudo updatebd no funciona

```
sudo updatebd
sudo: updatebd: command not found
```

ya hice la instalación:

```
sudo apt install locate
updatebd
```

Resultado:

```
Command 'updatebd' not found, did you mean:

command 'updatedb' from deb mlocate
command 'updatedb' from deb locate
```

Answer (score 0):

El comando correcto es **updatedb** (de update **D**ata **B**ase).

Estás invirtiendo la b y la d del final del comando.

Como tu lo pones se te informa de que el comando no existe:

```
$ sudo updatebd
sudo: updatebd: command not found
```

Poniéndolo como **updatedb** no te dará problemas (Si no hay errores el comando se ejecuta sin mostrar nada):

```
$ sudo updatedb
$
```

Extracto de la man de updatedb:

```
UPDATEDB(1)                                                  General Commands Manual                                                  UPDATEDB(1)

NAME
       updatedb - update a file name database

SYNOPSIS
       updatedb [options]
```